# How to print added or suppressed lines containing a certain string with commit sha-1?

Tags: git, shell

I'm looking for property changes that may have happen between two commits or two dates.

For the sake of this example properties are injected this way in the code `@Value("${my.property}")`. So I'm looking for lines changes having the `@Value` string.

What I've been able to achieve so far, which is already good, is the following command. It gives me every changes happened since some date or between commits, etc. (depending on the args of course).

```
git log -S@Value --since=2014.5.16 --patch-with-stat
    | grep "^[+-].*@Value"
    | sed 's/^\([+-]\).*\${\([a-z0-9:.-]*\).*/\2 \1/'
    | sort
    | uniq
```

Which gives me the following output

```
some.consistency.level -
some.feature.global.consistency.level -
some.cluster.name +
some.feature.store.data.center.name +
some.feature.store.metrics.enabled:false +
some.feature.store.metrics.polling.period:60 +
some.feature.store.slow.metrics.enabled:false +
some.feature.store.consistency.level +
some.feature.store.consistency.level -
some.feature.store.read.consistency.level +
```

While I would like something similar to that (short sha-1, regex extract of the property, -/+, commit message) :

```
abcdef1 some.consistency.level -                         # some change
abcdef2 some.feature.global.consistency.level -          # rename porperty
deffb34 some.cluster.name +                              # added cluster name
ef903ad some.feature.store.data.center.name +            # adds metrics
ef903ad some.feature.store.metrics.enabled:false +       # adds metrics
ef903ad some.feature.store.metrics.polling.period:60 +   # adds metrics
ef903ad some.feature.store.slow.metrics.enabled:false +  # adds metrics
fa3fb9e some.feature.store.consistency.level +           # refactors stuff
fa3fb9e some.feature.store.consistency.level -           # refactors stuff
fa3fb9e some.feature.store.read.consistency.level +      # refactors stuff
```

Which would be really useful to track why this property has changed, *fields* of course could be added or removed (like showing the commit date or the author).

`git blame` or `git annotate` don't seem fitted for that task as they apply to a file and don't output a diff. Tweaking the `git log` format don't seem relevant too.

I'm not sure how and if this is possible to craft such a script easily. Thoughts.